# How to create my own certificate authority for IIS?

Tags: c#, ssl

I am tired of buying SSL Certificates for my clients.  We spend thousand dollars per month on average. ***Can someone please show me how to start my own certificate authority (Not the the self-sign certificate)?*** This SSL is for IIS.

It seemed like IIS can issue self-sign and OpenSSL can do the same thing and **I do not want it** unless it can provide a full SSL like Verisign and other big companies.

Comment: There is some information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority, which however says "This market has significant barriers to entry since new providers must undergo annual security audits ... to be included in the list of web browser trusted authorities."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to roll your own certificate authority (suppose for closed in-company infrastructure), you start by (surprise, surprise) creating a self-signed certificate, which will act as a root CA certificate. Then you generate the first child certificate - intermediate CA certificate. Now put the private key of the root certificate to the safe place - most likely you will not need it for years. Intermediate CA certificate is used to issue end-user (or other sub-CA) certificates.

If you want your certificates to be recognized by standard browsers and other client software, you need to find a way to get your public root certificate to the list of trusted roots in the OS itself and in those browsers and clients, if they have their own certificate storages. This is a complicated procedure, different for each OS and each browser. It involves repeating audits, compliance to tough procedures etc.

Again, if you create certificates for internal company use only, you can make software installer (or just write a custom script or application) that will add your certificate to the trusted root list on each user's computer. This can be done in code almost without problems, but the user will have to (a) run that script or program, and (b) confirm addition of the certificate. For some browsers or other client applications the procedure can be more complicated.

The procedure of creating a CA is quite a complex topic. I suggest that you read some books on PKI before you proceed. Here are the great books I'd recommend:

1. [Rsa Security's Official Guide to Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072254947)
2. [PKI: Implementing & Managing E-Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072131233)

Comment: If you're a domain admin then you can do Remote Installation Services, as opposed to having ppl run the program individually.

Answer (score 2):

Creating your own certificate authority is not an issue. Your issue is creating a certificate authority that *other people will trust*!

There is absolutely no point you creating your own unless all your users are prepared to accept certificates signed by you, and this is a pretty unlikely scenario unless you have a small number of users that are prepared to trust your root CA.

Getting them to trust you involves them all installing your root CA as a trusted CA on their web browsers which is hardly good security practice.

Unless you work in a controlled environment, and all your users are internal, or you have a very suggestible group of users who will do whatever you say - I would recommend you forget this idea.